# Error: BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.GameObject, UnityEngine.Transform, Un

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Following is my code to generating, moving, and destroying obstacles:

```
#pragma strict
var speed:float=1.5f; 
var obstart:Transform; 
var obstack:GameObject; 
var pos:Transform; 
var i:int=0;

function Start () {
    Invoke("Obs",4.0f);
}

function Update () {}

function Obs(){
    pos=obstart;
    pos.position = new Vector3(
        obstart.position.x,
        obstart.position.y,
        obstart.position.z + (i*5)
    );
    i=i+1;
    obstack=Instantiate(obstack,pos,Quaternion.identity);
    obstack.rigidbody.velocity=Vector3.left*speed;
    Destroy(obstack,10.0f);
    Invoke("Obs",4.0f); 
}
```

I am facing an error:

> BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate' for the argument list '(UnityEngine.GameObject, UnityEngine.Transform, UnityEngine.Quaternion)' was found.

Comment: `pls help me` it is generally a good idea to *write down what have you already tried*. stackoverflow people tend to wish to see the efforts on your side to have an idea how were you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

`Instantiate` second argument is `position` not `transform`

```
 obstack=Instantiate(obstack,pos.position,Quaternion.identity);
```